# Hostaliases file with an IP address

Tags: hosts

The `HOSTALIASES` environment variable allows users to set their own host aliases instead of having to `sudoedit` `/etc/hosts` (more details, e.g., at http://blog.tremily.us/posts/HOSTALIASES/)

However, with `/etc/hosts` I can alias IP addresses to names and names to names, whereas `HOSTALIASES` only seems to work with name to name aliasing.

I tried:

```
cat > .hosts
work 10.10.0.1
g www.google.com
^D
export HOSTALIASES=$PWD/.hosts
```

and now

```
curl g #works 
curl 10.10.0.1 #works
curl work #doesn't work
```

Can I make `curl work` work without needing to edit a file I don't have write permissions to (`/etc/hosts`) ?

Comment: It works for me.  How does it say with `curl -v work` and `getent hosts work`?

Comment: $? == 6: ... couldn't resolve host 'work' ... AND  $? == 2: <no output>. `getent hosts  g` gets me $? ==  0: 2a00:1450:400c:c05::67 www.google.com

Comment: Got it.  I'm on GNOME desktop and using NetworkManager and dnsmasq.  It returns `10.10.0.1` for A record query for domain name `10.10.0.1.`, as if `inet_aton()` applied.   BIND returns NXDOMAIN for such queries.  You can see it by `host 10.10.0.1. <nameserver address>`

Comment: So I suppose it regards the aliased string `10.10.0.1` as a domain name as-is, simply queries to libnss resolver modules with it.

Comment: Btw you can utilize a public service like http://xip.io/ to get arbitrary IPv4 address using domain names: `work 10.10.0.1.xip.io`.

Comment: "work 10.10.0.1" - on my machine, the /etc/hosts file has the IP address followed by the names?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`HOSTALIASES` feature is provided by the resolver funtion `gethostbyname()` in glibc.  In this function an alias look up result is passed as-is to subsequent libnss module calls specified by `hosts:` in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, therefore if there's no module which can handle it, `gethostbyname()` will end up with failure.

Note that in most programs numerical address notation like `10.10.0.1` and `2a00:1450:400c:c05::67` is processed by `inet_aton()` `inet_pton()` `getaddrinfo()` before `gethostbyname()` is called.

Some DNS servers, including dnsmasq, return valid address records to queries with a numerical address string as if `inet_aton()` applied to it: e.g. they return A record `10.10.0.1` to query for FQDN `10.10.0.1.`.  However, other servers including BIND just return NXDOMAIN for such queries.  So you cannot rely on this to define `work 10.10.0.1` in your `HOSTALIASES` as an alternative of `/etc/hosts`.

One possible workaround is to utilize a public DNS service like [xip.io](http://xip.io/) to get resolvable FQDNs for arbitrary IPv4 addresses.  For example you can define `work` for `10.10.0.1` like this:

```
work 10.10.0.1.xip.io
```

Comment: Thanks. I've installed and started dnsmasq and the ip line in the HOSTALIASES file works now.

Comment: `xip.io` resolves to NXDOMAIN as of 2021-12-30. `nip.io` seems to have replaced it.